# Remote SSH Tunnel external access

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I've setup a remote ssh tunnel from my Raspberry Pi, which is behind a NAT, to my vServer using the follow command:

```
ssh -ngNTfR 62.75.145.118:2209:localhost:22 root@unkn0wn3d.com
```

62.75.145.118 is the A record of unkn0wn3d.com

I've set

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

on unkn0wn3d.com sshd_config.

When I now try to connect directly to my Pi via

```
ssh pi@unkn0wn3d.com -p 2209
```

it says

```
ssh: connect to host unkn0wn3d.com port 2209: Connection refused
```

Netstat outputs

```
# netstat -a | grep 2209
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdom:2209 *:*                     LISTEN
```

## Edit:

iptables output:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I've set the GatewayPorts to clientspecified on the vServer. The Raspberry Pi has Gatewayports still set to no.

I can reproduce the issue, the errors remain the same.

Comment: It sounds like a firewall issue, post the iptables ouput from your vServer. Also check the auth log on the vServer.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. The `netstat` output in your question is what would be expected in case the configuration said `GatewayPorts no`. Could you go over the debugging steps mentioned in your question again and verify that you can in fact reproduce it as described? Are you certain you edited `sshd_config` on the correct server and reloaded the configuration file afterwards?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.
I had a MatchUser Rule a few lines above the GatewayPorts and it looks like it was causing the issue.